# Does Neopixel require a continuous signal to keep the LEDs lit?

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver

I want to use Neopixels in a project which lights up some Neopixels, does a lot of computation and then changes some other Neopixels. Now since the program is synchronous I do not want to lose the present lit Neopixels.

*I want to know whether the Neopixels remember their state or do we need to provide continuous pulses to control the Neopixels?*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neopixel's core functionality is exactly that: being loaded with a value (or three for RGB), and then holding that.

But: these are designed as shift registers, so that you can have many in a string. So to change the state of an LED down the string, you need to overwrite all the values of the pixels coming before that pixel in the string.

Comment: The 'shift registers' concept came to my mind. I just wanted to be sure :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you means what strings with WS2811, 2812, 2813 and similar, answer yes. They keep setting until it is rewriting or power down. After power up it "0"s, no light.